# Event Online Registration - Random Errors

Tags: civievent, online-registration

Random instances of errors occuring during online registration process. Registrants are completing the basic form - name and email, but the system responds "Oops you are already Registered" (certainly are not registered) or "email address is invalid" (nothing wrong with email address) or "log in required".

System settings have been checked - particularly the Permissions for Anonymous users, Profiles (create, edit and view), Event Registration and View.
Date and time is set ok for Online Reg, and the Registration Link is working OK.

The majority of registrations are working OK - but periodically we are getting these random errors.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look is the "Online Registration" section of the event configuration - particularly the multiple participants and duplicate matching rule.

If those seem reasonable (and the corresponding matching rules aren't messed up), then you'd want to look in your civicrm error log for additional clues. If the errors are kind of random, then I'd be suspicious that it's a bigger issue with your CiviCRM install (running out of memory or other resources? unusual caching setup?).

Comment: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer can be useful for non-techs wanting to see what is in their logs.